# How to remove backgroundimage from form1?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to remove background image with code.

It would look something like this

```
 public Form1()
    {
        this.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

The function "Dispose" doesn't work however.

Comment: Also I have realized I can make a new .png file (which would be a completely black background image) and I could replace the bg image with a black bg but it is more of a work-around than a solution.

Comment: This `InitializeComponent();` should be the first line in the constructor. Guess why?

Comment: __If__ you have actually __created__ the image (as opposed to just pulled it from resources) then you should indeed dispose of it, but not while it is still __in use__. So __first__ set it to null and __then__ (maybe) dispose of it!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did some extra research and found out that I must put the code

```
this.BackgroundImage = null;
```

But I must put it under form1_load, not public_form1

Answer (score 0):

There is no Dispose method for a `Control.BackgoundImage` property as this method is only for controls and would render the construct unusable.

You can use:

```
this.myPanel.BackgroundImage = null;
```

This will remove all content from a panel.

If you have assigned BackgroundImage, then you can use:

```
this.BackgroundImage = null;
```

Comment: _There is no Dispose method for a Control.BackgoundImage property_ Are you sure?

Comment: According to the documentation...
Using Dispose will make it unusable. And that is not his intention at the moment.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.dispose?view=net-5.0

Comment: Then there's a `Dispose()` method and an image is a _disposable_ object. Right? Your answer says otherwise. Also saying _as this method is only for controls_ is not accurate either. This method exists in any object that implements the `IDisposable` interface including the graphics objects. So you need to clarify that if you want to. I'm just giving you a hand here. Good luck.